# Como retornar um code erro no bash caso uma condição não seja verdadeira?

Tags: integração-contínua

Estou utilizando o **Travis-ci** para um processo de integração continua, entretanto, estou com dificuldade para realizar uma validação especifica após a instalação de alguns componentes (apache, php...).

Atualmente tenho a seguinte verificação (esse é o teste de validação):

```
STRING=$(curl -Is --head "$URL_CURL_CHECK" | grep -o "HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
function check {
    if [[ $STRING == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]]; then
        echo "sucesso"
    else
        echo "error"
    fi
}
```

URL_CURL_CHECK recebe a URL a ser verificada. Gostaria de poder lançar uma excessão no Travis-ci caso a condição deste if não fosse de sucesso, ou melhor, code return 0. Alguma ideia de como faço isso?

Comment: Nunca mexi com o Travis ... Mas ele entende código de saída? Caso sim, você poderia adicionar 'exit 0' na condição de sucesso e 'exit 2' na condição de error. Ou seja, seu script irá terminar como ERRO caso vá para o exit 2. Aí basta o Travis entender essa saída.

Comment: @Diego, feito. Pelos testes parece que funcionou bem.